# Что означает $countj = count($arr[$i])?

Tags: php

```
$arr = [
  ["рр","ыы","ыаы",20,"ыаы",2],
  ["ыпв","ып","вп",9,"впрр",4],
  [ "вр","вр","вр",30,"вр",5],
  ["врар","ароа","аоао",50,"ааоао",12]
];

for($i = 0, $counti = count($arr); $i < $counti; $i++)
{
  for($j = 0, $countj = count($arr[$i]); $j < $countj; $j++)
  {
  }
}
```

Хотелось бы понять что означает выражение $countj = count($arr[$i]), ибо впервые сталкиваюсь с подобным, да и в документации хотелось бы более понятного как для меня, новичка, изложения сути. Объясните в двух словах, чему равно и почему допустима такая запись, пожалуйста.

Comment: а что именно вас в этом выражении смущает? слева переменная, ей присваивается значение. справа функция возвращающая длину массива. аргументом является i-й элемент вашего двухуровнего массива.

Comment: Какая именно часть выражения непонтятна?  `$counti = ...`?  `count()`? `$arr[$i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$countj` - переменная
`count()` - функция возвращающая длину массива (кол-во элементов в массиве)
`$arr[$i]` - возвращает i-тый элемент массива
т.к. у вас массив массивов то `count($arr)` вернёт 4, первый цикл `for` будет работать пока `$i` будет меньше 4, а второй пока `$j` будет меньше 6 т.к. `count($arr[$i])` вернёт 6 так как у вас 4 массива по 6 элементов каждый типа `"рр"` и т.д. Например `$arr[0]` это `["рр","ыы","ыаы",20,"ыаы",2]` а

```
$arr[3]=["врар","ароа","аоао",50,"ааоао",12]
```